# Windows 2000 Server Can Only Connect to Windows Server 2012 Share Through IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, windows-server-2000, shared-printers

Server1 = Windows Server 2000

Server2 = Windows Server 2012

I am trying to view a list of available printers on a Windows Server 2012 machine (Server2) from a Windows 2000 server (Server1). I am trying to do this by hitting \Server2 share through explorer. When I do this, I get prompted for a username/password and entering my credentials which are Local Admin on both servers does not let me view a list of the printers. When I try this same thing using the IP address of Server2 (\192.168.1.102) I can view the printers perfectly fine and I am never prompted for credentials.

I've been troubleshooting this for days and have not been able to resolve the problem. The most promising solution I've found is setting the LmCompatibilityLevel on Server2 to "1" and the same setting on Server1 to "0", I changed the settings and rebooted, but this did nothing to help resolve the issue.

Does anyone else have any suggestions as to why this is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: You do know that Windows Server 2000 has been End of Life for a few years now, right? No new security patches are created, even when new security issues are discovered. Even a fully-patched Server 2000 machine is vulnerable to attack. It's highly irresponsible to still be using it. Getting that system updated to something supported is job #1.

Comment: Yes, we are very aware of that and have been putting a lot of pressure on our application teams. The application team has tried and failed to get this upgraded to a newer version. There is another project underway to migrate off this app, but I am a lowly server person so I have very little control of what the app team decides to do.